# Why does gradle not accept 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'

Tags: build.gradle, buildozer

[this the error of the build.gradle in ubuntu 22LTS terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bppZC.png)

im trying to deploy my kivy project to an android app with Admob Ads , but  am facing trouble with gradle when  i uncomented android.gradle_dependencies, but if i comment the android.gradle_dependencies its working and compile successfully

here are the my build.gradle file!

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1021100
        versionName '1.0'
        manifestPlaceholders = [:]
    }

    
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
        doNotStrip '**/*.so'
        
    }
    

    

    

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
            java {}
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation ''com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0''
    
}
```